# merge json and remove duplicates ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following json

Suppose my selection in mobile then this fields will be generated

```
{"Style":"convertible","Year":"2010","Color":"green"}
{"Style":"convertible","Year":"2010","Color":"red"}
```

And if my selection is bike then this field will be generatd

```
{"model":"2012","mileage":"20kmph","Color":"red"}
```

How do i achieve the above result.

**Edit-1**

I have the form in which some of the fields with be auto generated based on category selection. I have converted the auto generated fields to json and stored in database as single column.
[Image url](http://postimg.org/gallery/5t2ow4g0/)

I don't know how to explain can you understand what I am looking for. Check out my screenshots for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming (for some crazy reason) that you will be using Ruby to do this.

But first, your expected output is wrong because you can't have a hash with duplicate keys:

```
{"Color": "green", "Color": "red"}
```

...is impossible. Same goes for the "Year" keys. Think of keys within a hash as Highlanders. THERE CAN ONLY BE ONE (of the same name). Therefore, your actual expected output would be:

```
{"Style":"convertible", "Year":"2012", "Color":"red", "name":"test"}
```

Or whatever. Anyway...

Step 1: Convert JSON to a Ruby Hash

```
require 'json'
converted = JSON.parse '[{"Style":"convertible","Year":"2010","Color":"green"},
{"Style":"convertible","Year":"2010","Color":"red"},
{"name":"test","Year":"2012","Color":"red"}]'
```

Step 2: Merge them

```
merged = {}
converted.each { |c| merged.merge! c }
```

Now the merged variable should look like the above actual expected output.

The only problem left is deciding which duplicate keys override which other duplicate keys. What matters here is the order in which you merge the hashes. The ones merged last overrides any existing duplicate key/values. Hope that helps.

Comment: The reason why i need this is I am trying to create refined search if the year 2012 and 2010 present in the json then it should highlight it. Otherwise I need to hide others. Whether I am in right way?

Comment: Then don't merge or union. Keep them as separate JSON objects so that they can have there own keys. It doesn't seem like merge is what you want here. Can you rephrase the question?